# IMO 1989 Q1 Combinatorics, Solution verification

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

Prove that the set ${1, 2, . . . , 1989}$ can be expressed as the disjoint union of subsets $A_i (i = 1, 2, . . . , 117)$ such that:

(i) Each $A_i$ contains 17 elements;

(ii) The sum of all the elements in each $A_i$ is the same.

My Solution:

Note that the problem is invariant under translation, so we may centre it at $0$ and it will suffice to show that we can find 117 17 element subsets of the set

$-994,-993,...,994$

with each having its elements sum to $0$.

Now one of the $A_i$ must contain $0$ and hence an even number of non-zero elements, so for this set we can just pair positive with corresponding negative numbers.

The other 116 sets have an odd number of non-zero elements. For each of these, we can take 7 pairs of positive and corresponding negative numbers, but we must then complete the sets with a pair of numbers of a given sign, say $a,b$ and another number of the opposite sign, say $c$, such that $a+b+c=0$.

Now, since we have an even number of sets to construct by choosing elements in this way, we can deal with them in pairs, choosing $a,b,c$ in one, and $-a,-b,-c$ in the other. If we can find 58 such pairs of triplets and assign one triplet to each of the 116 sets, we will then be able to arbitrarily assign 7 positive-negative pairs from the remaining numbers to complete each set.

So the problem thereby reduces to the question of whether we can find 58 disjoint triplets $(p,q,r)$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct positive integers from the set {1,2,...,1994}, such that $p+q=r$. (We would then set $a=p$, $b=q$ and c=-r for a given set).

But this is clearly true, for example,

(100,200,300),(101,201,301),...,(158,258,416)

QED

I'm wondering if this solution is valid and if so would appreciate any suggestions for improvement. Thanks.

Comment: 1/ Your final sets as stated do not work since $ 101 + 201 \neq 301$.    $\quad$
2/ Your disjoint triples can only be chosen from $[997]$, not $[1994]$. $\quad$
3/ Personal preference for improvement: I would like to see the sets stated out at the end, instead of having to wade through all of your descriptions.  $\quad$ Apart from that, this looks fine.

Comment: (A) We have to count 100 to 157 (not 158) , Similarly 200 to 257 (not 258) , Sum will be 302 (not 301) to 414 (not 416). (B) We have to show that we have 7 Pairs for all the other Sets which are non-over-lapping. (C) We have show that total number is 1989. (D) Better to complete that with Example Explicit Solution , which will convince us that we have not made other Mistakes.

Comment: ""chosen from [997] , not [1994]"" , Something wrong here. It might be ""chosen from [986] , not [1989]"" , @CalvinLin

Comment: @Prem Right. "Chosen from [994], not [1987]". No idea how I had that typo.